# React Js Math Issues

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, jsx

I have an issue with the react js and I can't seem to get it to work.

I am making a value up to `3000` be turned into a percentage so that it will fill the bootstrap percentage bar by the correct amount but I keep getting random values out of it.

I've worked out that when, for example, if I type 
`480` into the box I get an output percentage of `0.13` recurring, but if I type `480.00` I get `16%` which is correct.

Obviously I have to make it human proof by auto adding in the `.00` if they haven't specified something but I can't get it to auto add in.

```
onChange = (e) => {
    console.log(e.target.value)
    this.setState({ sliderValue: e.target.value });
    this.updateSlideValue();
}
updateSlideValue(){
    console.log(this.state.sliderValue);
    this.setState({slideValue: this.state.sliderValue / 3000 * 100});
    console.log("gets to update Slide Value");
    console.log(this.state.slideValue);
}
```

Then this is my html/jsx which calls it

```
<div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <div class="progress">
                <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-info" style={SlideValue}></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <input style={rangeSliderClass} className="range-slider__value form-control" onChange={this.onChange.bind(this)} type="number" value={this.state.sliderValue}></input>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: What browser are you using? It's not showing as 0.13 recurring in my browser (chrome)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a common mistake with React. Actually `setState` is asynchronous. Which means, when you call it, you have no garanty that it is updated at the next instruction.

```
// imagine this.state.value === 0
this.setState({ value: 1 })
// this.state.value => still 0
```

To be sure the value has been updated, there is a second parameter you can give to `setState` which is a callback that will be called whenever the state has been updated

```
// imagine this.state.value === 0
this.setState({ value: 1 }, () => {
  this.state.value // => 1
})
// this.state.value => still 0
```

Now, in your case, **I don't think you need to use the callback method**. I think you can compute the percentage directly in the `render` method as this is only a way to display raw data.

Here is what I would do if I were you:

```
onChange(e) {
    this.setState({ sliderValue: e.target.value });
}

render(props) {
  var slideValue = this.state.sliderValue / 3000 * 100;

  return (<div>
    ... 
    <div style={{ width: slideValue + "%" }}></div>
    ...
   </div>)
}
```

The `render` method is only called when the state is updated, so you are **sure** you get the last state here :)

Comment: I get an error saying the it doesn't understand render = (props){...} saying it expects a ; before the }

Comment: Thanks react can be a bit confusing with its errors sometime and not telling you exactly what you are looking at

Comment: Indeed this is a tricky part of React and often people fall into that trap. But it's actually an important behavior of React for performances reasons (batching all the state update in a single place and, thus, calling `render` only once)

Comment: Yeah I've only been learning it for a week as part of my first web dev job finding it alot of fun and very rewarding when you find something out or a new way of doing things, because what i find is that there are multiple ways of doing things is that true or are some of them bad practices and good practices